# How to convert string values to dates in Java?

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

I'm trying to convert some date values from access (MDB) database.

I'm getting this: 'Tue May 17 08:29:00 BRT 2011'.
But I want this: '2011-05-17 08:29:00'.

I already tried to use JAVA 8 new DateTime classes but didn't work.

Here is what I tried:

```
public class DateHelper {

    LocalDateTime dateTime;

    public DateHelper(String dateTime) {
        this.convertStringToDateTimeDeclaration(dateTime);
    }

    protected void convertStringToDateTimeDeclaration(String dateTime){
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        this.dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, formatter);
    }

    public String getDateTime(){
        return dateTime.toString();
    }
}
```

but I get

> "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Tue May 17 08:29:00 BRT 2011' could not be parsed at index 0"

Comment: When you say "didn't work", what does that mean? Are you getting an exception, is the output not what you're expecting? Also, I notice that the pattern you're using to parse is your desired *output* format, you need a pattern that will match the *input* format.

Comment: It says that couldn't be parsed. "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Tue May 17 08:29:00 BRT 2011' could not be parsed at index 0"

Comment: I'll try the input format..

Comment: It worked :D!!! Thanks @blm!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked but you might want to edit your comment to clean up the language.

Comment: @gord-thompson do you have another tip to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@blm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349263/blm) suggested:

I had just to match the input patterns like this:

```
protected void convertStringToDateTimeDeclaration(String dateTime){
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").;
        this.dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, formatter).withLocale(Locale.US);
    }
```

edit:

Added '.withLocale(Locale.US)' in the end of the LocalDateTime method chain to avoid the DateTimeParseException.

Thanks!!!